# Example involving the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am working on a Number Theory book and I have come across the following problem:

(Underwood Dudley 2nd Edition Section 5 Problem 3):

Solve the system:

x $\equiv 3(mod 5)$

x $\equiv 5(mod7)$

x $\equiv 7(mod11)$

I understand that I must use the Chinese Remainder theorem and I understand that the CRT states that if the GCD of these three numbers there exists a unique solution (mod 385), but my book gives me no instruction on how to go about finding this solution--other than cold hard calculation. Could I have some advice or direction on the method to solving this problem and the idea behind the method? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm..., it appears that 'the' technique to solve such systems is not illustrated in the book and instead is given as exercise 14. So I think the best you can do is to adapt the solution which is given to an example. (I have an older version of the book in which your problem is problem 4c, page 40.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method, sometimes called 'adding the modulus', that works fairly well for small moduli--I'll apply it to your problem:

Start with the congruence of the largest modulus, and as we go through each step, we watch for a number that satisfies any of the remaining congruences.:

$\pmod{11}: x\equiv 7\equiv 18$.  We notice that $18$ also satisfies $x\equiv 3\pmod{5}$.

So $x\equiv 18 \pmod{55}$.

Then $\pmod{55}: x\equiv 18\equiv 73\equiv 128\equiv 183\equiv 238\equiv 293\equiv348  $.  Here we notice that $348$ also satisfies $x\equiv 5\pmod{7}$.

Thus our solution is $x\equiv 348\pmod{385}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\equiv -2$ both $\pmod5$ and $\pmod7$, it must be congruent to $-2\equiv 33 \pmod{35}$.

Since $x+2\equiv 0\pmod{35}$, and $x+2\equiv 9\pmod{11}$, we want to know what $n$ makes $35n\equiv 2n\equiv 9\pmod{11}$. We see that $n=10$ does the trick.

So the answer is $x\equiv 35\cdot10 -2 = 348\pmod{385}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_1, a_2, a_3) = (3, 5, 7)$ and let $(n_1, n_2, n_3) = (5, 7, 11)$ and let:
$$
x = c_1a_1 + c_2a_2 + c_3a_3
$$
We want to solve for the coefficients $c_i$ so that they have the following special property:
$$
c_i \equiv \begin{cases}
1 \pmod {n_j} &\text{if } j = i \\
0 \pmod {n_j} &\text{if } j \neq i \\
\end{cases}
$$
If we can do this, then $x$ will automatically satisfy the system of congruences! For example, $x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$ because:
\begin{align*}
x
&= 3c_1 + 5c_2 + 7c_3 \\
&\equiv 3(0) + 5(1) + 7(0) \pmod 7 \\
&\equiv 5 \pmod 7
\end{align*}
So it remains to find these magical coefficients. I'll show you how to get $c_2$.

---

We want $c_2 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ and $c_2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and $c_2 \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$. From the last two conditions, we know that $55$ divides $c_2$. Now what multiple of $55$ would have a remainder of $1$ when divided by $7$? By inspection, notice that $-55 = (-8)7 + 1$ [if this step didn't jump out to you, you could use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find integers $u,v$ such that $55u + 7v = \gcd(55, 7) = 1$, then just take $c_2 = 55u$]. So we can take $c_2 = -55$.

---

Try to find the other two coefficients yourself!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general solution, just a solution based on your specific example.

$x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$

$ x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$

$ x \equiv 7 \pmod{11}$

First notice that

$x+2  \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and $ x+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$

Hence $x + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod{35}$. That is to say, $x = 35n - 2$ for some integer, $n$.

So \begin{align}
   35n - 2 &\equiv 7 \pmod{11} \\
   2n &\equiv 9 \pmod{11} \\
   2n &\equiv -2 \pmod{11} \\
   n &\equiv -1 \pmod{11}
\end{align}

So $n = 11m - 1$ and $x = 35(11m -1) - 2 = 385m - 37$

S0 $x \equiv -37 \equiv 348 \pmod{385}$